# Falha na inicialização do Tomcat 8 no Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat

Bom dia pessoal.

Estou tentando inicializar o tomcat 8 no ubuntu e não estou conseguindo.
Ao rodar o seguinte comando "sudo /tomcat/bin/startup.sh" está sendo gerado o seguinte log: [Log catalina Tomcat.txt](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1EC04DF97A994B86!3378&authkey=!AOzzWT15z7aXKGc&ithint=file%2Ctxt)

Ao rodar o comando netstat, o resultado é este:

```
root@livro:/home/silvairsilverio# netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        1      0 livro.c.orbita:http-alt 187.114.250.44.st:57386 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 livro.c.orbital-h:36647 metadata.google.in:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 livro.c.orbital-h:33700 metadata.google.in:http CLOSE_WAIT
tcp      833      0 livro.c.orbital-h:60730 metadata.google.in:http CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 livro.c.orbital-h:33704 metadata.google.in:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 livro.c.orbital-h:36645 metadata.google.in:http TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 livro.c.orbital-haw:ssh 187.114.250.44.st:57413 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 livro.c.orbital-h:36646 metadata.google.in:http ESTABLISHED
tcp      398      0 livro.c.orbita:http-alt 187.114.250.44.st:57385 ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  12     [ ]         DGRAM                    10970    /dev/log
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     59221
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    9629
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    59489
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11862
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     59605
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    59669
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9568
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10986
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10828
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11303
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     59650
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10875
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10085    @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12659
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    9630
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     59612
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10862
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11414
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     59613    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11585
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10074
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11213
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     59604
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10876    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11861
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10861
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    31555
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10987    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10854    @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9582     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    59652
root@livro:/home/silvairsilverio#
```

Qualquer ajuda será bem vida.

Comment: O erro que está no Log é: java.net.BindException: Address already in use. Verifique se existe outro programa utilizando essa porta e se necessário finalize.

Comment: Obrigado adelmo00, era isto mesmo, resolvi ajustando o arquivo server.xml para utilizar a porta 8181 ao ivés da porta padrão 8080.

Comment: Coloca sua solução como resposta e marca ela como aceita para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Editei o arquivo server.xml